# How to choose a Lock Identifier?

Tags: pallet, palletid, lockable-currency

In my pallet, I am writing a function that checks if a user has some minimum amount of free balance, and if they do, proceed with the transaction by locking a `DepositFee` amount. I found that `set_lock` perfectly fits my use case however it asks for a `LockIdentifier`. What should I use here? Can it be any single name or does it have to be unique for each transaction made to this pallet function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every account may have up to one lock in place from each of up to `MaxLocks` identifiers at any time.

Your identifier should not be already used in any Substrate crate. A simple namespacing scheme would be to use your pallet's name or obviously identifiable parts thereof. E.g. the lock used for the Phragmen Elections pallet is `"phrelect"`.

If your pallet may need to give a large number of independent locks for each account ID, then you will likely need to create a lock aggregation system within your pallet. For an example of this see `update_lock` in the Balances pallet.